# import variable

Tags: python, wxpython

attrubuI'm new to python but don't know how to solve this:

```
import wx

class myclass(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame',size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        button=wx.Button(panel,label="click me",size=(120,60))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickbutton, button)

        value=1

    def clickbutton(self, event):
        if self.value == 1:
            print("success")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=myclass(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I click the button I receive this error: "AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'value'". What am I doing wrong? / How do I import "value" into my "clickbutton"-function?

Edit:
OK, this one was solved. After that I wanted to modify it a little:

```
    self.dropdown=wx.Choice(panel,pos=(130,60))
    list = ['banana', 'apple', 'strawberry']
    self.dropdown.AppendItems(strings=list)

def clickbutton(self, event):
    if self.dropdown.GetStringSelection() == 'apple':
        print("success")
```

Actually this works.... but it took me a long time to figure out that I have to use "GetStringSelection()" in the last but one line. How can i display a list with possible attributes (like "GetStringSelection()") for "wx.Choice" (and other wx-classes) ? Or does a good website for this exists?

Edit 2:
Thanks again!
And I have a last question (sorry for asking step by step):

```
dir(wx.Choice)
```

works, but I have a given code with an obejct called "VarDecl". For this I get an error if I ask

```
dir(wx.VarDecl)
```

I'm lookin for an attribute like "HasChanged" for this VarDecl-object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File [...]    
if self.theVariable.HasChanged():
AttributeError: 'VarDecl' object has no attribute 'HasChanged'
```

Edit3:
OK, I think it has nothing to do with "wx", I think it comes from "re". (or still "wx"? I'm confused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `value=1` to `self.value = 1`. The `value` you have now is a local variable, which is discarded upon exiting the constructor.

**EDIT:** As for your second question, the built-in function `dir(object)` will give you a list of names (including methods) in the scope of the given object.
[More information available here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir)

**EDIT 2:** [The wxPython documentation may also be of use to you](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/)

**EDIT 3:** About the theVariable thing: Have you tried `dir(self.theVariable)`?

Comment: I've tried it, but without success. I got the hint, that there is no such attribut for VarDecl. I have to go another way: Store "theVariable" first and then compare with self.editor.GetText(). It's a bit tricky for me, but I give my best.